# Magnitude is returning a complex number if I precede it with Complex Expand?

Tags: functions, complex

I define a function called VoutCoin:

```
VoutCoin[Mut_, \[Omega]_, Lc_, Rc_] = 
ComplexExpand[Abs[I1coin* (j \[Omega] L1 + (j \[Omega] Mut)^2/(j \[Omega] Lc + Rc))]] /. values
```

I have the suffixes and the values defined:

```
M = 10^6;
k = 10^3;
m = 10^-3;
u = 10^-6;
n = 10^-9;
pf = 10^-12;


values = {
R1 -> 180,
C1 -> 9.4 n,
L1 -> 1.7 m,
Vin -> LaplaceTransform[Cos[2*\[Pi]*138 k*t - \[Pi]], t, s]
};

j = I;
s = j*\[Omega];
```

if I invoke the function as defined above with the following arguments, I get:

```
In[1030]:= VoutCoin[.5, 2*\[Pi]*10 k, 10 u, .1]

Out[1030]= {0. + 8.40133*10^-8 I}
```

if I remove the ComplexExpand preceding the Abs in the function, I get:

```
VoutCoin[Mut_, \[Omega]_, Lc_, Rc_] = Abs[I1coin* (j \[Omega] L1 + (j \[Omega] Mut)^2/(j \[Omega] Lc + Rc))] /. values // Simplify

In[1095]:= VoutCoin[.5, 2*\[Pi]*10 k, 10 u, .1]

Out[1095]= {8.40133*10^-8}
```

What is going on? Why would ComplexExpand[Abs[]] return a complex numnber?

In case anyone wants plugs this into Mathematica, I'm including I1coin below

```
In[1092]:= I1coin = I1 /. sol1

Out[1092]= {(Vin (Rc + I Lc \[Omega]))/(Mut^2 \[Omega]^2 - (-R1 + I/(C1 \[Omega]) - I L1 \[Omega]) (Rc + 
 I Lc \[Omega]))}
```

Thank you in advance for your help....

--------Edit Per Request_----------------------

```
M = 10^6;
k = 10^3;
m = 10^-3;
u = 10^-6;
n = 10^-9;
pf = 10^-12;

values = {
R1 -> 180,
C1 -> 9.4 n,
L1 -> 1.7 m,
Vin -> LaplaceTransform[Cos[2*\[Pi]*138 k*t - \[Pi]], t, s]
};

j = I;

s = j*\[Omega];

eq1 = Vin - I1 (R1 + 1/(j \[Omega] C1) + j \[Omega] L1) -j \[Omega] Mut I2 == 0;
eq2 = I2 (j \[Omega] Lc + Rc) + j \[Omega] Mut I1 == 0;

sol1 = Solve[eq1 && eq2, {I1, I2}]

I1coin = I1 /. sol1

VoutCoin[Mut_, \[Omega]_, Lc_, Rc_] = ComplexExpand[Abs[I1coin* (j \[Omega] L1 + (j \[Omega] Mut)^2/(j \[Omega] Lc + Rc))]] /. values // Simplify

 In[1159]:= VoutCoin[.5, 2*\[Pi]*10 k, 10 u, .1]

 Out[1159]= {0. + 8.40133*10^-8 I}
```

Question is about result out[1159] --- I don't understand why Mathematica returns a complex number for a magnitude.  It seems to happen when I precede Abs with ComplexExpand

Comment: I seem to get results in terms of `s` when I run your code. Are you sure you included all definitions?

Comment: maybe one more.....thank you....

Comment: `CopmlexExpand` **assumes** all variables are real. If they're not you'll get unexpected errors. check out `ComplexExpand[Abs[t]] /. t -> I`

Comment: @yohbs I do not understand your point. Your replacement rule is not injecting the value `I` inside the `ComplexExpand`; it is simply changing it in the result of the evaluation. For injection, you could try: `With[{t = I}, ComplexExpand[Abs[t]]]`, which returns $1$, as I would expect.

Comment: You define VoutCoin with `=` and not `:=` which means that the value is precacluated assuming `I1coin` is real. then you probably inject a non-real number. `sol1` is not defined in your question so it's hard to tell. It would be easier if you provided one contiguous block of code with all definitions that produces the error.

Comment: @yohbs, added the code in one block per your suggesion....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider your `values` rule:

```
Vin /. values
```

> -((I ω)/(76176000000 π^2 - ω^2))

So, values is replacing `Vin` with a pure imaginary number. Now, your `VoutCoin` function is basically:

```
f[ω_] = ComplexExpand[Sqrt[Vin^2]] /. values
```

> Sqrt[-(ω^2/(76176000000 π^2 - ω^2)^2)]

Here, `ComplexExpand[Sqrt[Vin^2]]` evaluates to just `Sqrt[Vin^2]`, and then you replace `Vin` with a pure imaginary number, hence you get the square root of a manifestly negative number. So, naturally:

```
f[1.]

(* 0. + 1.33009*10^-12 I *)
```

is imaginary.

If you move the closing bracket of the [`ComplexExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand) so that it include the `values` replacement, then you will get a real answer:

```
VoutCoin[Mut_,ω_,Lc_,Rc_] = ComplexExpand[
    Abs[I1coin*(j ω L1+(j ω Mut)^2/(j ω Lc+Rc))] /.values
] //Simplify;

VoutCoin[.5,2*π*10 k,10 u,.1]
```

> {8.40133*10^-8}

Comment: thank you for taking the time to explain and demo this to me.  much appreciated